# Does an invisible creature trigger an opportunity attack if it makes a ranged attack

Tags: dnd-4e, opportunity-attack, invisibility

Does an invisible creature trigger an opportunity attack if it makes a ranged attack?

And if it does, is the opportunity attack -5 as it's against an invisible creature?

Where does the invisibility go down in the sequence?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## No, Invisible Creatures Do Not Provoke Opportunity Attacks

#### (From Enemies That Can't See Them)

From page 221 of the **Rules Compendium**:

> An invisible creature can take advantage of several benefits.
>
> - It can't be seen by normal forms of vision.
> - It has total concealment against any enemy that can't see it.
> - It has combat advantage against any enemy that can't see it (but it still has to be able to see the enemy).
> - ***It doesn't provoke opportunity attacks from enemies that can't see it.***

(Emphasis mine)

While it is true that attacking will cause a creature to no longer be hidden, it will still retain the benefits of being hidden (including not provoking an opportunity attack) until the attack resolves.  On page 153:

> **Not Remaining Hidden:** If the creature takes an action that causes it not to remain hidden, the creature retains the benefits of being hidden, such as combat advantage, until the action is resolved.  The creature can't become hidden again as part of that same action.

As defined on pages 196-197, opportunity actions (such as the opportunity attack) are interrupts, and therefore occur before their triggering action resolves:

> **Interrupt:** Just like an immediate interrupt, an opportunity action interrupts its trigger, taking place before the trigger finishes.

Putting all of this together, you can see that the opportunity attack would not be provoked by an invisible creature making a ranged attack against an adjacent creature.  The invisible creature's "doesn't provoke opportunity attacks" benefit would not be lost until the attack resolves, but an opportunity attack would have to occur prior to that attack resolving, and therefore the opportunity attack never occurs.

To break it down into a sort of sequence of situational facts/events:

1. Creature A is invisible to Creature B, and they are adjacent to each other.
2. Creature A uses a ranged attack against Creature B, becoming un-hidden as a result of making an attack action.
3. *Ordinarily, this is when an opportunity attack would be triggered from Creature B, but since Creature A has the benefits of invisibility against Creature B, the opportunity attack does not occur.*
4. Creature A's attack resolves.
5. Creature A's invisibility benefits are now lost.

So, at the time that the opportunity attack would ordinarily trigger, the attacking creature still has the benefits of invisibility and no opportunity attack can trigger.

Comment: Worth noting that if there are more than one Ranged attacks during the same action (such as Secondary attack, or multi-attack, but not a single attack with multiple targets), and the Invisibility effect is lost when attacking, then it is reasonable to treat the *now visible* creature normally and grant AoO versus second, third etc Ranged attacks (do check that secondary attacks *are* Ranged, they don't have to be e.g. if the secondary attack is due to applied poison).

Comment: Appreciate that invisible creatures don't provoke AoO, but attacking drops the invisibility, so one interpretation is they are therefore attacking while visible, so the other creature get an AoO

Comment: @NeilSlater this is incorrect, the benefits of hidden are retained for the entire action.

Comment: @SteveC that happens *after* the attack is resolved.

Comment: @wax eagle: Invisibility is not Hidden.

Comment: @NeilSlater As wax eagle said, that's not right.  Secondary & tertiary attacks occur as part of the same *action*, and invisibility benefits are not lost until an action has resolved entirely.  Thefore, if a ranged attack has a secondary attack as an effect, the secondary attack simply occurs following the initial attack, as part of the same action, and only after the **entire** action resolves is the hidden benefit lost.

Comment: @NeilSlater Invisibility IS Hidden.  Page 152: "Being hidden means being silent and invisible."  And also Page 221: "The most common way to become invisible is to use the Stealth skill to become hidden."

Comment: @NeilSlater no, but hidden *is* invisibility.

Comment: @wax eagle: My point - benefits of Hidden remain for whole action. Including being effectively Invisible during that action. But if you are not Hidden, just Invisible with a power that lasts until you attack, then there is no such rule covering Invisible that says *benefits of Invisible remain for whole action*. The rule is specifically about Hidden, which in general is a more powerful effect.

Comment: @NeilSlater exactly, I hadn't seen your comment when I made mine, but you've got the ruling exactly right here.

Comment: @NeilSlater The implication in the book is that the rule about remaining hidden is the same as the rule about remaining invisible.  Page 153 makes specific mention of the combat advantage benefit being kept until after the action resolves when a creature does not remain hidden, and the combat advantage benefit is actually a benefit of invisibility in particular.  The only place in the book where combat advantage is given for being hidden, is in the rules that say combat advantage is given for being invisible.  (continued...)

Comment: If you retain the advantage throughout the action while becoming un-hidden (not seen and not heard), which means you could potentially be both seen AND heard, then it only makes sense that you would also retain the same advantage throughout the action if go from being invisible to being seen.  How is there any mechanic difference between going from unseen & unheard to seen & heard, vs going from simply unseen to seen?  If you have an advantage from being unseen, that is kept throughout the action when going from hidden to un-hidden, it only makes sense the same applies when becoming visible.

Comment: The way I look at it, is that going from hidden to un-hidden is actually a more extreme case of the enemy's change in awareness of you, vs going from invisible to seen.  If an enemy had absolutely no awareness of you at all by sound or sight and then suddenly gained both sound and sight of you, and even after such a strong shift in awareness, you still retain your benefit until the end of the action... then why *wouldn't* you retain the same benefit during a lesser shift of awareness from only unseen to seen?

Comment: @calahan09: It's probably such an edge case (Invisible that ends in reaction to "an attack", plus power that grants two separate attacks) that it doesn't matter which way it goes. But the mechanical difference is between Invisible and Hidden - they are simply different, but connected. This is similar to being Immobilized versus being Grabbed, similar edge cases crop up there when you can end the former but not the latter.

Comment: But since there is no explicitly defined rule about when you lose your invisibility benefits for becoming visible, I would assume that the "not remaining hidden" rule as far as losing hidden benefits is meant to be all-encompassing, since the invisibility benefits are a large part of the hidden benefits, it makes sense to me that you could look at losing invisibility as a sub-instance of losing hidden, and thus that rule applies to both since there is nothing else explicitly defined in regards to invisibility and how it's mechanics differ from hidden in terms of when benefits are lost.